# splitting string at word - keep the left hand side

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have string, in the middle somewhere (different lengths to left and right) I have this sequence of characters (there is a space to the immediate left and right)

> to:

Is there away to split at this point and return the characters on the left i.e. given this string:

*Here is some text to: and here is some more text of a different length*

The result I would like is:

> Here is some text

Answer (score 3):

Use `IndexOf` combined with `Substring`:

```
string s = "Here is some text to: and here is some more text of a different length";

int length = s.IndexOf("to:");

if (length > 0)
{
    s = s.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you know you have that word in there:

```
String s = "Here is some text to: and here is some more text of a different length"
String result = s.Split(new String[] { "to:" })[0];
```

You split the text and take the 1st part.

If the substring you chose is not in the string, `result` will just contain the plain `s` - no change.

Comment: 1. Fixed, thanks! 2. If you have more than one occurance of `to:`, it will just take the first part.

Comment: The code works, but it goes through the whole string, which IMO is unnecessary. `.IndexOf` & `.SubString` has a better performance.

Comment: @DannyChen Can't really argue with that, but `Split` is simpler, so I felt I have to show that solution also.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier with [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim FirstSplit as String()
FirstSplit = Name.Split(",")
fname = FirstSplit(0).Trim()
```